# TabHost visual style (2.x and 4.x)

Tags: android

I'm trying to mimic visual style of TabHost widget. The problem is that the style is quite different on 2.x and 4.x platforms. On 2.x it's gray with icons while on 4.x is has nice background (a blue strip) and no icons.

I have found that the style Widget.TabWidget declared as:

```
<style name="Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget</item>
    <item name="ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripLeft">@android:drawable/tab_bottom_left</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripRight">@android:drawable/tab_bottom_right</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">fill_horizontal|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:tabLayout">@android:layout/tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

so some values of the style is what I'm looking for i.e. tabLayout, divider, etc.
Is it possible to reference to that style and get TabHost background/layout?

Comment: Those aren't TabHosts on Android HC+. Those are ActionBar tabs.

Comment: TabHost is deprecated but it exists on all Android versions including the latest jelly bean. Actually it doesn't matter that it's deprecated, I just want to copy the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [this library](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) that mimics the style used on honeycomb's (and above) style called "holo" style .

i didn't see a tabhost example there ,but it might exist nevertheless since it has all kinds of views .